# Mongo $inc on array where index is dynamic

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to increment a value sharded by hours.

```
let doc = {
  $inc: {
    totalMessages: 1,
    'activity.' + (new Date()).getHours(): 1
  }
}
```

My goal is to have a count for every full hour. E.g. amount of messages done between 9 and 10 o'clock.

But string concatination doesn't work.
How can I do that?

I also want to make use of $inc upsert behavior.
so:

```
doc.$inc.activity[(new Date()).getHours()] = 1
```

does not work neither and leads to the following MongoError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument
or to TypeError: Cannot set property 'xx' of null

Thx

Comment: Thank you :D That worked well:
doc.$inc['activity.' + d.getHours()] = 1

Comment: I'll leave as answer and you can mark as accepted for others people might find useful in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your dynamic value within brackets: `doc.$inc['activity.' + value]`
  This should work.